# How to clear cache of projectile file in spacemacs?

Tags: projectile, spacemacs

I am using `spacemacs` and often use the `SPC p f` key binding to find files in a `projectile` project. But even after removing a file from a git, `SPC p f` will show me that deleted file.

I tried using `SPC p I` to invalid the cache, but that didn't work.

How to resolve the problem?

Comment: Can you verify that the bindings are made correctly? What do you get when you do `C-h k SPC p l`? It should be bound to `projectile-invalidate-cache`. Also check if `M-x projectile-invalidate-cache` works.

Comment: I am using spacemacs, it re-defined some key mapping.

Comment: It's alright to change the key mapping. I am asking you to confirm if the keys are bound to the command you think should be bound. Nevertheless, did using M-x approach work?

Comment: It was because Spacemacs uses `recentf` for sorting project files. In older Projectile version, even after you deleted the files, Projectile still reused the outdated file list from `recentf`. In later Projectile version, clearing Projectile cache also cleans up `recentf` file list and removed the deleted files. You should update to latest Projectile and try again.

Comment: It isn't the case in your situation, but it took me a minute to realize that the cache is based on version control (git), not the directory itself. So a deleted file will keep showing up until you stage the deletion in your VCS.

Answer (score 38):

Type `M-x projectile-invalidate-cache` and you'll see the command with the bindings listed next to it. For me the bindings said `M-m p I` which was correct, and should be the default I suspect for holy mode (`spc p I` for evil mode).

Comment: I wish there is a way to automatically do this.

Comment: @LiXinyang there's a setting you can put in your config that says to never cache project files. It however causes project operations to slow down on any project with lots of files. `'(projectile-enable-caching nil)`

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @Xinyang Li question on automating cache invalidating process, I started to use snippets below to clear projectile cache for current project after I switch between projects and clear cache of all the projects after initialization of emacs.

```
(add-hook 'projectile-after-switch-project-hook (lambda ()
      (projectile-invalidate-cache nil)))


(add-hook 'after-init-hook (lambda ()
    (mapc (lambda (project-root)
        (remhash project-root projectile-project-type-cache)
        (remhash project-root projectile-projects-cache)
        (remhash project-root projectile-projects-cache-time)
        (when projectile-verbose
            (message "Invalidated Projectile cache for %s."
                (propertize project-root 'face 'font-lock-keyword-face)))
        (when (fboundp 'recentf-cleanup)
            (recentf-cleanup)))
        (projectile-hash-keys projectile-projects-cache))
    (projectile-serialize-cache)))
```